# How to concatenate two Twig variables in a Twig loop

Tags: loops, concatenation, twig

I have a simple loop which requires me to concatenate my loop counter variable `loop.index` within my main value variable (hope that makes sense) but I can't get it working.

Is it even possible? See below...

```
{% for article in section.articles %}
    {{ article.internationalText~{{loop.index}} |raw|nl2br }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use twigs [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function which was added in version 1.2. It is designed for accessing a "dynamic" attribute of a variable.

```
{% for article in section.articles %}

    {{ attribute(article, 'internationalText' ~ loop.index) |raw|nl2br }}

{% endfor %}
```

Note, benatespina's answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
{% for article in section.articles %}

    {{ article.internationalText~loop.index |raw|nl2br }}

{% endfor %}
```

This should work.